# Convert from hexa to Arabic text with Python

Tags: python, linux, utf-8

I  build a code that convert a hexadecimal string into Unicode format but after print,  the output the conversion not work while when making copy from output and put it in print(u'output') the Arabic text appear

Python Code

```
input ="062A06450020062A62C062F064A062F0020";
i = 0 ;
n ="\\"+"u";

    while i < (len(input)):
        n +=   input[i:i+4] + "\\"+"u";
        i = i + 4;

output = str(n[0:(len(n)-2)]) ;
print (u'%s'%output)
```

Output:

```
\u062A\u0645\u0020\u062A\u62C0\u62F0\u64A0\u62F0\u020
```

Copy output and use print Unicode:

```
print (u'\u062A\u0645\u0020\u062A\u62C0\u62F0\u64A0\u62F0\u020')
```

Arabic text appear

Comment: There is no `020` codepoint in Unicode. Are you missing a hex digit?

Comment: The output you show as expected is *not Arabic text*. Minus the invalid `\u020` at the end, you actually have `تم ت拀拰撠拰`.‎ Looks like you are missing a digit in the middle.

Comment: Ok If  I remove '\u020' from the input and run my code still the output appear "\u062A\u0645\u0020\u062A\u62C0\u62F0\u64A0\u62F0" not the arabic Text

Comment: No, you are missing a `0` in the middle, before `62C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't produce Unicode codepoints by prepending `\u` in string *values*, no, because the `\u` sequence is part of the string *literal* syntax. It is used by the Python parser, no the interpreter, to produce Unicode values.

Your input is also too short; you'd need *one more digit* somewhere, it looks like you are missing a `0` in the middle before the presumably in the middle before `62C`.

You essentially have hexadecimal UTF-16 in big-endian order; just decode from hex and decode as `utf-16-be`:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
unhexlify(input).decode('utf-16-be')
```

Demo, with corrected input data:

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> input ="062A06450020062A062C062F064A062F0020"
>>> unhexlify(input).decode('utf-16-be')
'تم تجديد '
>>> print(unhexlify(input).decode('utf-16-be'))
تم تجديد
```

Comment: Thanks alot Pieters... but when I use your code I get an error as below. "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Comment: @Moustafa this example is for Python2 and you probably use Python3 - try `codecs.decode(input, 'hex').decode('utf-16-be')`

Comment: `>>> input ="062A06450020062A062C062F064A062F0020"`
`>>> input.decode('hex').decode('utf-16-be')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    input.decode('hex').decode('utf-16-be')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: @Moustafa better add it in question - it will be more readable.

Comment: @furas I use your recommanded line for python 3 but still not working. `>>> import codecs                                                                                                                                      
>>> codecs.decode(input, 'hex').decode('utf-16-be')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    codecs.decode(input, 'hex').decode('utf-16-be')
LookupError: unknown encoding: hex`

Comment: @Moustafa: ah, sorry, I assumed you were using Python 2 (because you formatted your output with a `u'...'` string literal). Will update.

Comment: @Moustafa it is strange that you don't have `"hex"`. Maybe try `"hex_codec"` instead of `"hex"`. Or check what python version you use.

Comment: @furas: the `hex` codec was re-introduced in Python 3.4, so the OP is using 3.3 or older.

Comment: @MartijnPieters now I get it - I use `3.5` and `2.7` and both have "hex" :) I checked in doc for 3.3 and `"hex_codec"` should work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks alot for your support & help