# How do I output unicode from its 16-bit hexcode?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a list of unicode characters that I want to write to a file. However, I only have them as their raw 16-bit hexcode.

How can I output proper unicode characters from a hexcode, i.e. how to I get from

```
00DF
```

to

```
ß
```

?

Note that `ß` is `\u00DF` in unicode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert unicode codepoint to UTF8 hex in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867866/convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf8-hex-in-python)

Comment: `s= '\u00DF';s.__repr__()`? or `s.__str__()`?

Comment: Why did you tag the post with `utf-8`? There's nothing about it in the question.

Comment: The linked question doesn't exactly fit, but you might be able to get enough hints from the comments over there. I guess you're looking for `chr(int('00DF', 16))`, but the question isn't really clear enough to me.

Comment: @lenz Your suggestion works. If it were an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: @lenz: Note: For surrogates (so unicode code point > 16 bits) the example will not give the correct result, but the example is the correct way to go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from hexa to Arabic text with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927544/convert-from-hexa-to-arabic-text-with-python)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463940/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-string-to-character-with-that-code-point

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Very good point about the surrogates. [Martin Pieters' answer linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40927836/) is the way to go I'd say, ie. `binascii.unhexlify` with `decode('utf-16-be')`.